# Get value of each "selected" cell of datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have intialisd a datatable like this

```
var t = $('#domains_list').DataTable();
```

Now my problem is how to alert value of each 2nd column of rows which have class 'selected'?

say for the below codes:

1. To alert no. of rows selected. The below code works fine

```js
alert(t.rows('.selected').data().length +' row(s) selected' );
```

2. to alert data of 1st column of rows having class 'selected'. The below code works fine

```js
alert(t.cell('.selected', 1).data());
```

3. To alert data of 2nd column of all selected class rows. The below code is buggy

```js
t.cells('.selected').eq(1).each(function() {
    alert($(this).data());
});
```

How can I solve problem #3?

Thanks

Comment: "to alert data of 1st column of rows having class 'selected'. The below code works fine" Are you 100% sure about that?

Comment: There is no point in using eq, or nth-child if you are targeting by class.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `:nth-child(2)` instead of `.eq(1)` selector:

```
 t.cells('.selected :nth-child(2)').each(function() {
    alert($(this).data());
 });
```

> :nth-child() Selector: selects all elements that are the nth-**child** of their parent.
>
> :eq() Selector: Select the element at index n within the **matched set**.

Comment: here's an issue.... even if i am selecting 4 rows, i am getting only 1 alert..... why??

Comment: when i am selecting 4 rows, i mean i am making 4 rows get their class as 'selected'..... then even if i am clicking the button, i am geting only one alert instead of 4.....

Comment: the no. of alerts for your code, should be the no. of rows selected.... but i am getting only one alert

Comment: still getting the same only one alert

Comment: can you create the fiddle

Comment: there's lot of files and code, soits not possible to create fiddle

Comment: just with relevant DOM.